# Add Polygons to R shiny leaflet map

Tags: r, leaflet, shiny, shapefile

How do I add polygons from [Global Administrative areas](http://gadm.org/), so they are clickable.

The simple way describe in the `docs` that I tried is

```
adm <- getData('GADM', country='UKR', level=1)
leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% addPolygons(data=adm, weight = 3, fillColor = col)
```

But imagine I want a leaflet map that will have onClick actions later.

Based on [SuperZip](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-examples/blob/master/063-superzip-example/server.R), I need to have something similar to

```
  map <- createLeafletMap(session, "map")
  session$onFlushed(once=TRUE, function() {
     map$addPolygon(...) 
  })
```

However, there is no addPolygon method and I am confused how will it work for `SpartialPolygons`.

I also tried converting to `geoJSON`, similar to https://ropensci.org/blog/2013/10/23/style-geojson-polygon/ or this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23546184/add-polygon-to-map-r-leaflet), but doing

```
  polys <- fromJSON(<json data file>)
  map <- createLeafletMap(session, "map")
  session$onFlushed(once=TRUE, function() {
    map$geoJson(polys)
  })
```

Gives me an error

```
Error in func() : attempt to apply non-function
```

Is there a way to do it? Or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: what onclick action do you want to have later on? Simple popups? or more?

Comment: Simple popups is fine to start with

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I am not sure I really understand the problem, although I read through the question a couple of times. However the code below seems to work for me, as it can easily be combined with a simple `onClick` event, like a pop up displaying the name of each adm. unit:

````
---
title: "Ukraine"
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---

```{r, echo=FALSE, message=F, warning=F}
library(leaflet)
library(raster)

adm <- getData('GADM', country='UKR', level=1)

popup <- paste0("<strong>Name: </strong>", 
                        adm$NAME_1)

leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  addPolygons(data=adm, weight = 2, fillColor = "yellow", popup=popup)
```
````